# Error: bad 'S3method' directive: S3method("")

Tags: r, devtools

When I try to `document()` or `build()` my R package using the devtools package, I get the error message:

```
Error: bad 'S3method' directive: S3method("")
```

I was working on a function `tabyl()` when this error occurred and now I can't get rid of it, even with much tweaking of my function headers.  The function should be working now; for reference, the headers are:

```
#' @export
tabyl <- function(...) UseMethod("tabyl")

#' @inheritParams tabyl
#' @describeIn tabyl Create a frequency table from a vector, returned as a data.frame, showing percentages and with or without including \code{NA} values.  A fully-featured alternative to \code{table()}.
#' @export
tabyl.default <- function(vec, sort = FALSE, show_na = TRUE, ...) {
  ...
}

#' @inheritParams tabyl.default
#' @param .data a data.frame.
#' @param ... arguments passed to tabyl.default.
#' @describeIn tabyl Create a frequency table from a variable in a data.frame, returned as a data.frame, showing percentages and with or without including \code{NA} values.  A fully-featured alternative to \code{table()}.
#' @export
tabyl.data.frame <- function(.data, ...){
...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At one point you used `document()` with problematic values that placed the line:

```
S3method("")
```

At the top of your NAMESPACE file.  This will cause `document()` to fail before that line can be overwritten in the new NAMESPACE file.

Delete that line from the NAMESPACE file manually, then you can proceed with working on the package, running `document()` like normal.

Comment: Or just delete the NAMESPACE file and let roxygen2 recreate it.